# How to apply classes to dynamically generated content?

Tags: html, css, jsx, tailwind-css

In tailwind, there is a feature (which I find ***very*** annoying at times) called preflight that turns most of the HTML elements to appear like normal text. And the documentation says that if you want your lists to remain unchanged, you can just do the following:

```html
<ul className="list-disc list-inside">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

But the thing is, I have dynamically generated content and I can't find a way to apply those to it. Does anybody know how this can be done?
I tried wrapping it in a div with the classes but no luck.

```
<div className="list-disc list-inside">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you have dynamically generated content?

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically generated content, you can inject CSS styles using Javascript/jQuery. Please note that the following code has to run *after* the content is dynamically generated, so it overrides the default styles. Here is a simple example that sets the `color` property for `li` elements to red.

```js
$('li').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-disc list-inside">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `@layer` directive as shown in the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives.

```
@layer base {
  ul {
    @apply list-disc list-inside;
  }
}
```